# NSString stringWithFormat problem

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

I have such a problem:
double calcValue;

```
NSString *buf = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%14f", myCalculator.calcValue];
```

buf = "7.142857";

istead of

buf = "7.1428571428571423";

I tried to format it in such ways: @"%f".
But when I tried @"%14.9f" 9 signs after comma displayed.

Whats the problem? And how can I solve it? Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but `stringWithFormat:` doesn't seem to format doubles properly. You might try this approach:

```
double calcValue=7.1428571428571423;
NSString *buf=[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:calcValue] stringValue];
```

which will set `buf` to `@"7.142857142857142"`.

For tighter control over number of digits, you could use a `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: the answer is using "%g". it do all things together!

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, the correct format would be `@"%.14f`.

What you did, `@"%14f"` says you want up to 14 digits, before the decimal, but you didn't specify digits after.